# Black screen in react code - possible firebase auth issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, tailwind-css

this code is giving me a blank screen i have no idea as to why i would assume its firebase auth or the logic giving me trouble im running this in vscode and its compiling sucessfully

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const SignUp = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const signUp = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
        userCredential.user
          .updateProfile({
            displayName: name,
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("user name added");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto flex justify-center pt-6">
      <form className="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-xl" onSubmit={signUp}>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2"
            htmlFor="name"
          >
            Name
          </label>
          <input
            className="w-full border border-gray-400 p-2 rounded-md"
            id="name"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2"
            htmlFor="email"
          >
            Email
          </label>
          <input
                        className="w-full border border-gray-400 p-2 rounded-md"
                        id="email"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Enter your email"
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-4">
                      <label
                        className="block text-gray-700 font-medium mb-2"
                        htmlFor="password"
                      >
                        Password
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="w-full border border-gray-400 p-2 rounded-md"
                        id="password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Enter your password"
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-red-500 text-xs mb-4">{error}</div>
                    <button
                      className="bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-600 text-white py-2 px-4
                      rounded-md"
                      type="submit"
                    >
                      Sign Up
                    </button>
                    <Link
                      to="/login"
                      className="text-indigo-500 hover:text-indigo-600 font-medium py-2 px-4"
                    >
                      Already have an account?
                    </Link>
                  </form>
                </div>
                
              );
            };
            
            export default SignUp;
```

was trying to make a signup page for my website that took in email and password to authenticate but also took a name to display on profile

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you get any errors in the console of your browser when the page goes blank?

Comment: no error it complies successfully

Comment: When I get these issues, I find that removing a bunch of the components from the return helps me narrow down the issue. Give it a try and let us know if you're still having issues. I don't see anything obvious here.

Comment: have you tried making the `signUp` function async? It could be returning the promise. Instead of awaiting. Just from quick lookover